# Storing serial print data from arduino in array

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm using a bluetooth connection to send serial data from Arduino to my Android app.  The code I'm using to connect the Android device is `BluetoothChat.java` which is sample code you can find if googled.

The sample code displays the data in a `ListView` and I want to store it in an array.

Here is the code for reading the serial print from the Arduino...

```
case MESSAGE_READ:

            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add(readMessage);
            int a = readBuf.length;

            //coordinates[] is the exact length necessary as given by double[a], and contains no more and
            //no fewer positions than required.

            double coordinates[] = new double[a];

            //Check the values of the data in readBuf[] and make the necessary conversions to store in the
            //variables.
            for(int i=0; i<a; i++){

                int val=readBuf[i];

                /*
                *(int) val/8 will divide val and round down to the nearest integer.
                *val%8 divides by 8 but takes the remainder which is the value of
                *all variables above x1, though the math works with x1.
                */

                coordinates[(int) val/8] = val%8;

            }
```

I think I stored the data correctly.  But when I use `coordinates[]` it doesn't change the text in the `TextView` I have setup.  Below is the code to set the text.

```
if(readBuf.length==4){
                double x1 = coordinates[0];
                double x2 = coordinates[1];
                double y1 = coordinates[2];
                double y2 = coordinates[3];

                r = new Regression(x1, x2, y1, y2);
                r.computation();

                leftLung.setText("Left Lung "+ r.leftLungDamage() +"% hit");
                rightLung.setText("Right Lung "+ r.rightLungDamage() +"% hit");
                heart.setText("Heart "+ r.heartDamage() +"% hit");
                liver.setText("Liver "+ r.liverDamage() +"% hit");
                smallIntestine.setText("Small Intestine "+ r.smIntestineDamage() +"% hit");
                largeIntestine.setText("Large Intestine "+ r.lgIntestineDamage() +"% hit");
                stomach.setText("Stomach "+ r.stomachDamage() +"% hit");
                spleen.setText("Spleen "+ r.spleenDamage() +"% hit");
                gallbladder.setText("Gallbladder "+ r.gallbladderDamage() +"% hit");
                lKidney.setText("Left Kidney "+ r.lKidneyDamage() +"% hit");
                rKidney.setText("Right Kidney "+ r.rKidneyDamage() +"% hit");
                pancreas.setText("Pancreas "+ r.pancreasDamage() +"% hit");
                venaCava.setText("Vena Cava "+ r.venaCavaDamage() +"% hit");
                dAorta.setText("Descending Aorta "+ r.dAortaDamage() +"% hit");
                aAorta.setText("Ascending Aorta "+ r.aAortaDamage() +"% hit");
            }
```

Regression works on its own as a standalone Java application.

Answer (score 0):

```
coordinates[(int) val/8] = val%8;
```

This line strikes me as weird array asignment. You create an array with length of readBuf. So why use something like `(int) val/8` to store values in the array.

Probably

```
coordinates[i] = val%8;
```

is what you want. Or at least `coordinates[i] = something` is the proper way to store values in an array using a `for` loop.